# xcopy wildcard source folder name to destination

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wildcard, xcopy

I want to copy from a wildcard source folder to a destination folder:

```
xcopy a:\parentfolder\n* x:\parentfolder
```

Only folders starting with "n" should therefore be copied to the destination.

Any help to get this working would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what's wrong with what you've got? If there's an error, post it. Otherwise, state what's working differently than you expect.

Comment: Is there an error?  What doesn't work?

Comment: I have deleted a few files in the destination folder in order to to test whether the above command will copy the missing files across. Even though I get no error from the above xcopy, the missing files are not copied either.

I have also tried the xcopy command as follows:
xcopy "E:\parentfolder\N*.*" "N:\parentfolder\" /D /F /I /Y /R

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/ad "a:\parentfolder\n*" ') do xcopy "a:\parentfolder\%%a\*" x:\parentfolder\
```

As you have it, XCOPY assumes that `n*` is a filespec, and there's no way to tell it otherwise.

Comment: Thanks so much Magoo, though it seems there might be a little bug somewhere. I have tried your code a few different ways, but get an error: "%%a was unexpected at this time"

Comment: Ok, I got it working! :-)

It seems the problem was with the double %%a .... ? Changing it to sing le %a did the trick. Thanks Magoo !! :-)

Comment: The final tweak was the /s switch for xcopy.

Hope this is helpful for others.

Comment: @RenéSchutte The double `%` is necessary when running this command from a batch file. From the command line you only need a single `%`, as you discovered.

Comment: @user5428856 - The spces between the switches are optional with `dir` although I normally use them. The `\` between the sourcespec and destination was definitely an error - and one which has been here for more than 18 months! Good spotting!

Answer (score 3):

If you first CD to the folder you want to copy it will work:

```
a:
cd \parentfolder
xcopy /s n*.* x:\parentfolder
```