# Batch command to copy files from source to destination

Tags: batch-file, cmd, window

I need to copy set of files from source to destination, below is the command I am using and its working fine. but folder "29749659" is dynamic and its name always changes. Under "unzipped" only one folder will exist.

```
xcopy /y C:\Nageswar\unzipped\29749659\files\products\Essbase\EssbaseClient\api\include\* C:\Jenkins\jobs\Planning\branches\develop\workspace\planning\Jni\include
```

Is there any way to write a command

Comment: Try this - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209474/xcopy-wildcard-source-folder-name-to-destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209474/xcopy-wildcard-source-folder-name-to-destination)

Comment: Thanks a lot its working. The solution is for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/ad "C:\Nageswar\unzipped\*" ') do xcopy /y "C:\Nageswar\unzipped\%%a\files\products\Essbase\EssbaseClient\api\lib\*" C:\Jenkins\jobs\Planning\branches\develop\workspace\planning\Jni\lib\linuxamd64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /d %%a in (C:\Nageswar\unzipped\*) do xcopy /y "%%a\files\products\Essbase\EssbaseClient\api\include\*" C:\Jenkins\jobs\Planning\branches\develop\workspace\planning\Jni\include
```

should accomplish this - the `for /d` scans the target directoryname for directorynames and applies each found in turn to `%%a`